# DataTables Server-side Processing: Joining two DB Column into One DT

Tags: php, mysql, datatable, server-side

I am new to DataTables Server Side Processing.
How can I join/combine two database column (db) in one datatables column (dt) using the server side script ? I tried:

```
$columns = array(
    array( 'db' => 'id', 'dt' => 'id' ),
    array( 'db' => array('firstname', 'lastname'),'dt' => 'priest' )
);
```

and it's NOT working. What is the right what to do that? Thank you!
I'm using DataTables-1.10.16.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it server side and then hide the column you don't want in js. 
For example let's say you have a table with 3 columns: id, name and link. 
To combine the link into the name do:

In html (header and footer) show both columns (we will hide the column dynamically in javascript):

```
<th>#</th><!--this is column 0 with id-->
<th>name</th><!--this is column 1 with name including a tag-->
<th>link</th><!--this is column 2 with link-->
```

In javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#table_id').DataTable( 
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "ajax.php"
        },
        "order": [[ 0, "asc" ]],//ordering by the id (usefull)
        {"columnDefs": [
            { "visible": false,  "targets": [ 0 ] },//hiding the id
            { "visible": false,  "targets": [ 2 ] }//hiding the link column
        ]
     });
});
```

In the ajax php script also describe both columns:

```
$columns = array(
    array( 'db' => 'id',  'dt' => 0),
    array( 
        'db' => 'name',
        'dt' => 1,
        'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
            return '<a href="'.$row[2].'" target="_blank">'.$d.'</a>';
        }
    ),
    array( 'db' => 'link',   'dt' => 2 )

);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late answer,

Actually in demo spss.php class you cannot merge them but we have a solution,
Which is using "Column Render"

Go to Server Side Processing file and
write a something like that (16 just assuming if you've 5 column u should write 6)

```
array( 'db' => 'database column',     'dt' => 16 )
```

Then go to the client;

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
 "columnDefs": [ 
            {
                // The `data` parameter refers to the data for the cell (defined by the
                // `data` option, which defaults to the column being worked with, in

                "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
                    return data +' ('+ row[16]+')';
                },
                "targets": 11
            },
            //This is makes db 16 row nonvisible
             { "visible": false,  "targets": [ 16 ] }
        ],
    } );
} );
```

"Targets":11 means i would like add something to  11. column.